# Error: The class 'SingleTickerProviderStateMixin' can't be used as a mixin because it extends a class other than Object

Tags: android, flutter

Just learning flutter Animation. using with `SingleTickerProviderStateMixin` IDE giving me this error :

> The class 'SingleTickerProviderStateMixin' can't be used as a mixin because
>   it extends a class other than Object

**My code:**

```
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

  class AnimationControllerOutputBody extends StatefulWidget with  {
    @override
    _AnimationControllerOutputBodyState createState() =>
        new _AnimationControllerOutputBodyState();
  }

  class _AnimationControllerOutputBodyState extends State<AnimationControllerOutputBody> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

    AnimationController animation;

    @override
    void initState() {
      super.initState();
      animation = new AnimationController(
        vsync: this,
        duration: new Duration(seconds: 3),
      );
      animation.addListener(() {
        this.setState(() {});
      });
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return new GestureDetector(
        child: new Center(
          child: new Text(
            animation.isAnimating
                ? animation.value.toStringAsFixed(3)
                : "Tap me!",
            style: new TextStyle(
              fontSize: 50.0,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        onTap: () {
          animation.forward(from: 0.0);
        },
      );
    }

    @override
    void dispose() {
      animation.dispose();
      super.dispose();
    }
  }
```

**What's my problem in code?**

Comment: Why is there a `with` on `AnimationControllerOutputBody` ?

Comment: I found this here: https://sergiandreplace.com/flutter-animations-the-basics/. Just running their code. But getting this error.

Comment: you link doesn't have such `with`

Comment: check middle of the post. or search with this class. "The basic example" headline

Comment: I'm talking about `AnimationControllerOutputBody` not `_AnimationControllerOutputBodyState`

Comment: there is. check again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176003/discussion-between-yeahia2508-and-remi-rousselet).

Comment: [github repo of the example](https://github.com/sergiandreplace/flutter_animations/blob/43adf1b9e08781f2a2516e5062ebea393e041592/lib/pages/animation_controller_output.dart#L15) : No it's not there

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add to `analysis_options.yaml`

```
analyzer:
  language:
    enableSuperMixins: true
```

See also https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/analysis_options.yaml#L24

Comment: Interesting. Why is this needed ?

Comment: Worked !! Thanks again ^_^

Comment: This is an experimental feature the Dart team wants to remove and redesign mixins after Dart 2.0, but they kept it in its experimental form for now, because Flutter depends on it.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer what is this "new `mixin` syntax for super-mixins" talked about here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/22870/files

Comment: That replaces the old experimental superMixin implementation my answer refers to.

Comment: It now says that enableSuperMixins is deprecated

Comment: Because it is enabled by default and can not be disabled. You don't need this setting anymore.

Answer (score 5):

I my case I used `SingleTickerProviderStateMixin`, Please just use  `TickerProviderStateMixin` instead of `SingleTickerProviderStateMixin`